# Polynomial such that $a\mid p(a)$, for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $a\neq 0$. (Problem with divisibility in $\mathbb{R}$.)

Tags: polynomials

The problem is as follows: Let $p$ be a polynomial of order $n$ s.t. there exist polynomials $q_m$, $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $m\leq n$, $q_m(x)=(-1)^m$ s.t. $p(x)=q_m(x) x^m+r_m(x)$, and $p(a)$ is divisible by $a$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $a\neq 0$. Under which conditions is $1$ a zero of $p$?

The first thing I have an issue with is that I see no sense in the first part of the statement regarding the existence of $q_m$. Shouldn't that be true for all polynomials? It's just basically writing the polynomial as $+$ or $-$ one of the powers, and then the rest of the polynomial with one changed coefficient?

For example, if $p(x)=2x^3+x-4$, then we can write it as $p(x)=-x+(2x^3+2x-4)$ and $p(x)=x^2+(2x^3-x^2+x-4)$ and $p(x)=-x^3+(3x^3+x-4)$. Or am I missing something here?

Since I see no sense in that, I have an issue with handling the next part. Should I even consider the beginning or not? Also, if $a|p(a)$, I have a hunch that the only way for that to be true is for the free coefficient to be $0$, but I'm not sure how to prove that? But then again, how do we define divisibility in real numbers?

And in the end, I don't see how any of this would lead to finding out when $1$ is a zero of the polynomial.

Comment: What does divisibility mean for real numbers?

Comment: @lhf I don't know, it's just one of the things that baffles me in this problem.

Comment: What's the source of this question?

Comment: @AlexR. an exam in Elementary mathematics for undergrad math students (Croatia)

Comment: It's difficult to make any headway on this due to the really poor wording.

Comment: @AlexR. and how about if we assume that $a$ isn't real, but rather an integer, could that be more helpful?